# How does "gds.graph.project" actually work in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

While practicing in neo4j online course-[Neo4j Graph Data Science Fundamentals](https://graphacademy.neo4j.com/courses/graph-data-science-fundamentals/1-graph-algorithms/4-path-finding/), I'm confused about the following course example:

First, create the graph projection.

```sql
CALL gds.graph.project('proj',
    ['Person','Movie'],
    {
        ACTED_IN:{orientation:'UNDIRECTED'},
        DIRECTED:{orientation:'UNDIRECTED'}
    }
);
```

Then we can run Dijkstra’s shortest path.

```sql
MATCH (a:Actor)
WHERE a.name IN ['Kevin Bacon', 'Denzel Washington']
WITH collect(id(a)) AS nodeIds
CALL gds.shortestPath.dijkstra.stream('proj', {sourceNode:nodeIds[0], TargetNode:nodeIds[1]})
YIELD sourceNode, targetNode, path
RETURN gds.util.asNode(sourceNode).name AS sourceNodeName,
    gds.util.asNode(targetNode).name AS targetNodeName,
    nodes(path) as path;
```

#### Question

Regarding `gds.graph.project` my understanding is that it creates a **subgraph (subset)** from the original graph.

However, in the creation of this subgraph, there are no nodes with the `Actor` label. So why is it possible to execute `MATCH (a:Actor)` when performing the Dijkstra algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MATCH (a:Actor)` clause is querying the full database, not the GDS projection ('proj'). Only the procedures whose names start with `gds.` access the GDS.

Also, a node can have any number of labels. So, a `Person` node can also have the `Actor` label, or `Director`, or all 3.